# df.str.match with regex produces unexpected results

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

The following regular-expressions: `"O."` and `"O[ACTG]"` yield different results when applied to the df `str.match` method, as demonstrated below.

The former (`"O."`) works as expected, but is unable to exclude `data` on the 8th row from being overwritten.

The latter (`"O[ACTG]"`), though it preserves the 8th row value, as expected, completely ignores the nested list structure and updates the `data` column with individual values on the list.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"find":['TO', 'GO', 'CO', 'AO', 'OT', 'OG', 'OC', 'OA', 'OO'],
"data":[[6,7],[5,6],[3,4],[1,2],[2,4,6,8],[2,4,6,8],[1,3,5,7],[1,3,5,7],"C"]})

# These lists are obtained from applying a filter to 
# the dataframe subsets given by (A) and (B) below to 
# remove [1,4,6,7] from the nested lists.
new_values_len5 = [[2, 8], [2, 8], [3, 5], [3, 5],[]]
new_values = [[2, 8], [2, 8], [3, 5], [3, 5]]


# I would like to apply the filter to only those rows 
# in which the find column string is "O"-something 
# (rather than something-"O") but not "OO".

# (A) this works...
df['data'][df.find.str.match("O.")] = new_values_len5

#   find    data
# 0   TO  [6, 7]
# 1   GO  [5, 6]
# 2   CO  [3, 4]
# 3   AO  [1, 2]
# 4   OT  [2, 8]
# 5   OG  [2, 8]
# 6   OC  [3, 5]
# 7   OA  [3, 5]
# 8   OO      []  # I want to exclude "C" from being overwritten


# (B) but this doesn't
df['data'][df.find.str.match("O[ACTG]")] = new_values

#   find    data
# 0   TO  [6, 7]
# 1   GO  [5, 6]
# 2   CO  [3, 4]
# 3   AO  [1, 2]
# 4   OT       2  # !!nested structure in `new_values` is ignored.
# 5   OG       8
# 6   OC       2
# 7   OA       8
# 8   OO       C  # "C" is kept intact here but the nested list structure of `new_values` is destroyed.
```

I would like to know what causes this behavior and how to avoid it when applying regex to filter data in a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['data'][df.find.str.match("O(?!O)")] = df['data'][df.find.str.match("O(?!O)")].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in [1,4,6,7]])
```

Result:

```
  find  data
0   TO  [6, 7]
1   GO  [5, 6]
2   CO  [3, 4]
3   AO  [1, 2]
4   OT  [2, 8]
5   OG  [2, 8]
6   OC  [3, 5]
7   OA  [3, 5]
8   OO  C
```

Comment: I want to apply the filter to only those rows in which the `find` column string is "O"-something (rather than something-"O") but not "OO".

Comment: My question pertains to the unexpected regex behavior; but this is a good hint at the solution to my problem.

Comment: I would use `df['data'][df.find.str.match("O.")] = df['data'][df.find.str.match("O.")].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in [1,4,6,7]])` which works as expected.

Comment: Interestingly, `df['data'][df.find.str.match("O[ACTG]")] = df['data'][df.find.str.match("O[ACTG]")].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in [1,4,6,7]])` doesn't have the same problem in this case.

Comment: I have updated the regex to "O(?!O)" like this it excludes the "OO" and let the letter "C" without [ ]. :=)